# Objective-C Generated Interface Header and CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Once again, I come to the hive-mind for assistence!

I'm using CocoaPods and I have the `X-swift.h` to expose some `Swift code to`Objective-C`.

**Imagine the following situation:**

`NetworkService` inherits Siesta's `Service` class (Siesta added via CocoaPods) and is `public`. Since Siesta's `Service` class is in fact a `NSObject`, my `NetworkService` type will get publicly exposed via the `Objective-C` via the `X-swift.h` header and the compiler will send grief and tears my way since the `X-swift.h` doesn't know what a `Service` (or `BOSService` to be precise) is. 
The `X-swift.h` header does not reference the frameworks provided by CocoaPods, so the header has no idea what some of the types from libraries added via CocoaPods are.

Another example of this is the `GoogleMapsSDK`. Conforming a Swift type to `GMSMapViewDelegate` requires it to be a `NSObject`, thus automatically exposing it via the `X-swift.h` header and causing the same build issue.

I've solved these issues temporarily by wrapping these `NSObject` types with pure Swift types (so they don't get exported via the `X-swift.h` header), but I feel there has to be a more robust solution to this.

Looking forward to hearing thoughts about this!

Comment: Have you tried importing the framework directly rather than just your main module?

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow. How would that help? Just to clarify more, I have a couple of types that I need to expose to ObjC, all from my main module. The issues is that these types use types from frameworks included via CocoaPods, and get included in the `X-swift.h` generated header, which doesn’t have any knowledge of these CocoaPods types, as it doesn’t reference them.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity!

What I meant was trying `#import "Siesta-swift.h"`.

Comment: The `X-swift.h` header is not mutable, as it's re-created every time the project's successfully built, thus you cannot apply modifications to it I'm afraid.